# Page width wider than html

Tags: html, contao

I have a little problem on my website, [alexander-pastor.de](http://alexander-pastor.de). If you resize the window
to a width below 1000px, the width of the page would be more than 1000px, which is wider than
the html-tag.

Adding max-width:100% or overflow-x:hidden to certain elements would resolve this  on my computer browsers (discarded this workaround), but not on my mobilephone's browsers! Moreover this kind of approach would be more of a workaround than a real solution to the problem.

According to [Page Speed Insight (google)](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=alexander-pastor.de)  the .inside divs would be too wide, but however i cannot confirm this with the Chrome developer tools?!

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Alex

Note: I messed with some .htaccess file and some Contao CMS setting according to this  guide (contao.org/de/news/contao-fuer-google-page-speed-optimieren.html). Can't see any relation though, but thought it might be useful to mention to track down the problem!

Sorry was prohibited from posting more than two links due to lack of reputation, sry :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say `If you resize the window to a width below 1000px, the width of the page would be more than 1000px, which is wider than the html-tag. ` Could you clarify, maybe provide some code, and/or give a drawing/screenshot?

Comment: added the following css code, which helped: @media (max-width:1050px){*{max-width:100%;}}, but still interested in a "real" solution!

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me right now. Where in your CSS did you add this `@media (max-width:1050px){*{max-width:100%;}}`?

Comment: uploaded a screenshot (couldnt add one to the post due to lack of reputation): http://www.alexander-pastor.de/files/latest/img/scr.png

Comment: i added the lines here: http://alexander-pastor.de/assets/css/fc9e14bb5702.css (lines 783-785)